# Does anyone have the .wgt files for the Samsung Gear 2 for Color Tiger's Power Off app which used the ir blaster? It's very old

Tags: tizen

So basically, 10 years too late, I got a Gear 2 smartwatch with an IR blaster. After many days of struggle I finally figured out how to sideload applications under the .wgt format using sdb and tizen sdk.

However, the Gear 2 has an IR blaster which is very limited. Color Tiger has a solution to this(or two, rather) apps which had a much wider variety of appliances to use the infrared blaster on. However, their first app's servers are dead.

The second app is called "power off" which basically is a Tv-B-Gone for the Gear 2 smartwatch.
If someone has the .wgt for this app I would truly and utterly appreciate it if you could send it over to me.

I have looked far and wide for the .wgt for this app. As I said previously, the other one didn't work because of the servers not connecting to the phone or some error.

This app is explicitly mentioned to not need outside connection or anysuch thing. However, I cannot find a SINGLE .wgt file of this app anymore.
For context, I was looking on xda forums in the Gear 2 page.

If someone has it please let me know!

Original app xda forum: https://xdaforums.com/t/power-off-turn-off-anything-in-the-room.2791350/

Comment: Might try the [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/) (internet archive) to see if might still be available/found?

Comment: I've tried, but I'm not very well versed in filtering based on file type   edit: i just realized that i should do that thannks paul!